# Ruby on Rails Cocoon Gem: Link to add association failed to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a person which has many statuses. I am using cocoon gem to have add status. The first status creates succesfully, but I cannot click on linkto_add_association to generate more status.

Anyone knows the reason behind it?

```
  #status
    = f.fields_for :statuses do |status|
      = render 'status_fields', f: status
    .link
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Status', f, :statuses, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success'
```

Below is my partial, which was a bit more complicated because they rely on other partials but all partials are working.

```
.row
  = render 'select_field', field_name: :status_type, f: f, select_options: ['Work', 'Sick', 'Study'], selected_value: f.object.status_type
.row
  = render 'date_field', field_name: :start_at, f: f
  = render 'date_field', field_name: :end_at, f: f
```

One more thing was: I have to do @person.statuses.build in new method in controller. If I don't do that, the fields_for section will not appear at all. This is weird to me because I thought I don't need to the build gem with cocoon gem.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you click on the link, do you get an error in the log?  (Meaning it's acting like cocoon doesn't exist) - If you use a browser element inspector and view the code that inside the link, do you see the generated html that will be pushed into place once you click?

Comment: Yes the html within the link is there. No log errors.

Comment: And if I don't add method @person.statuses.build, the first one won't appear as well.